# Validate form: if radio button is not checked show error message Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

I am trying to show an error message if the checkboxes are unchecked.

My solution doesn't work. Please see below. Not sure how to check this.

```
<input type="radio" name="comm">Yes
<input type="radio" name="comm">No

<div id="error_message"></div>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        myFunction();
    });

function myFunction() {
        var errortxt = "";
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('comm');
        for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked = false) {
                errortxt = "Error text";
            } else {
                errortxt = "";
            }
        }    
    document.getElementById("error_message").innerHTML = "<p>" + errortxt + "</p>";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake but you were on the good way of thinking, i did update your snippet with the correct synthax.

`=` is for assigning a value to a variable in javascript.

There are two operators for comparing values in JavaScript: strict equality === and “normal” (or lenient) equality == .

see http://2ality.com/2011/06/javascript-equality.html

```
for(const radio of radios){
  if(!radio.checked){
    errortxt = "Error text";
    break; // this will break the loop when a radio is not checked (will save precious time !)
  }
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        myFunction();
    });

function myFunction() {
        var errortxt = "";
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('comm');
        for(const radio of radios){
          if(!radio.checked){
            errortxt = "Error text";
            break;
          }
        }
    document.getElementById("error_message").innerHTML = "<p>" + errortxt + "</p>";    
    }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="comm">Yes
<input type="radio" name="comm">No

<div id="error_message"></div>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply using required in HTML can fix this issue

like this :

```html
<input type="radio" name="comm" required>
```

Comment: <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="category" id="flexRadioDefault1" required="required" >